# How can I redirect subdomain.mydomain.com to subdomain.mydomain.com/path/subpath

Tags: traefik

I am utilizing traefik through docker labels.

I have a container that has both kibana and elasticsearch and I would like to have frontend rules for both of them. I was able to do this by following [this PR](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/1257), but I ran into an issue of Kibana no longer redirecting `/app/kibana` with the subdomain.

My labels are as follows:

```
traefik.enable=true

traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https

traefik.elasticsearch.frontend.rule=Host:elasticsearch.mydomain.com

traefik.elasticsearch.port=9200

traefik.kibana.frontend.rule=Host:kibana.mydomain.com

traefik.kibana.port=5601
```

To clarifiy, previously when I navigated to `mydomain.com:5601`, I would be redirected to `mydomain.com:5601/app/kibana`. I would like this functionality back while still utilizing the subdomain.